# Locating files using Node.js and Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, include, filesystems

I am having trouble with local includes on the client side using Node.js and Socket.io. This may be to my PHP/Apache mindset I have had for file requests for most of my life.

On my server, I load the page likewise:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var path = require("path");
var server = require("http").createServer(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(server);
var mysql = require("mysql");

var port = process.env.PORT;
var ip = process.env.IP;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/client"));

//start opening socket connection handlers ...
```

And my files are organized likewise:

- games

  - libraries

    - bigInt
    - threejs
    - etc...
  - version_1

    - client

      - index.html
      - index.js
      - index.css
    - server.js
    - database.sql
  - version_2
  - version_3
  - etc...

Depending which version I want to run, I open that version's directory and run its server.js file. The line redirects the client to /client/index.html with the line `app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/client"))`. But now only files that are in the client folder are reachable by `<script></script>` or `<link>` tags but not those libraries in the libraries folder that I use across versions.

How do I change my code to be able to access files inside the libraries folder from /version_x/client/index.html while still directing the client to proper html file?

Note: Due to this issue, I have been forced to use only libraries with supported CDNs for the past couple weeks I have been learning Node.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line right after `var ip = process.env.IP;`:

```
app.use('/libraries', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'libraries'));
```

What this does is adding a new route to your application server. All your files inside your `/games/libraries` folder are now accessible via `/libraries`.

How does it work? Your `express` router uses different middlewares based on the provided paths. This line tells the router, to use the `static` middleware and serve files from `../libraries` when a HTTP Request for anything under `/libraries` comes in.

Comment: sorry, got it wrong from memory. Its `path.join()` (https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_paths)

Comment: One small follow up: I realize I have many libraries already installed via npm in the default folder node_modules. How could I include the libraries I want from this folder (I have a bunch of folders in here so I don't want to include the whole thing).

Answer (score 1):

You can serve more folders with express.static

```
//Serve Client Folder
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/client"));

//Server External Libraries Folder
app.use('/libs', express.static(__dirname + "/../libraries"));


 //Ex: <script src="libs/threejs/threejs.js">
 //Will load libraries/threejs/threejs.js
```

Comment: I am testing each of your guy's recommendations. However, the problem with your suggested file structure is that each version has its own socket connections and database structures.

Comment: oh sorry i misread it, so you only need to load the current version client folder and the external libraries folder. then just do the first part